kubectl unable to use raw api on node
I am trying to use kubectl's raw api on a node:
$ kubectl get --raw "/api/v1/nodes/ip-10-55-216-130.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal"
Error from server (NotFound): nodes "ip-10-55-216-130.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal" not found

But the node does exist:
$ kubectl get node ip-10-55-216-130.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal
NAME                                              STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
ip-10-55-216-130.us-gov-west-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   38m   v1.24.17-eks-ae9a62a

What's going on here?  Do I need to encode the node name somehow?

The node doesn't have a private DNS entry, will result in the kubelet log containing a node not found error. Ensure that the VPC where the node is created has values set for domain-name and domain-name-servers as Options in a DHCP options set. The default values are domain-name:<region>.compute.internal and domain-name-servers:AmazonProvidedDNS.
